# Seeing variables of other local functions in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have local functions in my main matlab script for example:

Exercise.m

[output 1, output2] = Function1(input);

... and so on

When I run Exercise.m script. I see only the variables of Exercise.m. But I want to see also the variables of Function1.m file. Therefore I go into Function1.m file and run it. But now I'm getting error "not enough input arguments".

What should I do to see variables of my other functions?

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint inside your Function1? This way Matlab will stop running while you're inside the function, and you will be able to look at its variables. Just remember that after you resume the application, you won't be able to see them anymore unless you return them to the main script as output.

Comment: What do you mean with _"What should I do to see variables of my other functions?"_ The variables only exist while the function is executed. After the function is left the variables are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options:

1. you should learn how to debug and use matlab's debugger.

for example, you can put a breakpoint  somewhere at the end of the function, when you'll run the script it will stop at the breakpoint showing you only the local memory of the function. You can then press continue, and exit the function and the rest of the code ill run.

2. avoid using functions, have one big script (dont)
3. use global \ persistent variable for only the variables you care about that takes place inside the functions. (not very recommended)

Comment: I love when i come across some mix of 2) and 3) options and that moreover start with `clc; clear all; close all;` ... just kidding :)